# stack() - how to preserve row names when stacking a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to stack columns of a data frame and maintain the row names. Here is an example.

```
tod<-format( seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "5 min"),
             "%H:%M", tz="GMT")
tod<-tod[1:length(tod)-1]
dat <- data.frame(A = 1:length(tod), B = length(tod):1)
colnames(dat)<-seq(as.Date('2015-05-01'), as.Date('2015-05-02'), by = 'day')

rownames(dat)<-tod
```

Which produces

```
          X2015.05.01 X2015.05.02
00:00           1         288
00:05           2         287
00:10           3         286
00:15           4         285
00:20           5         284
00:25           6         283
```

I then run

```
dat<-stack(dat)
```

Which returns

```
    values        ind
1      1 2015-05-01
2      2 2015-05-01
3      3 2015-05-01
4      4 2015-05-01
5      5 2015-05-01
6      6 2015-05-01
```

Is there a way to maintain the row names?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row names must be unique, so there is no way to replicate `tod` (*time of day*) in `rownames`.

I recommend you putting `tod` into an additional column after stacking:

```
new_dat <- stack(dat)
new_dat$tod <- rep(tod, times = ncol(dat))

#  values        ind   tod
#1      1 2015-05-01 00:00
#2      2 2015-05-01 00:05
#3      3 2015-05-01 00:10
#4      4 2015-05-01 00:15
#5      5 2015-05-01 00:20
#6      6 2015-05-01 00:25
```

If you still have doubt, let's try assigning `tod` to rownames:

```
rownames(new_dat) <- new_dat$tod
# Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
#   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

See? We get error.

Comment: Thanks. This is great